# create embedded json for autocomplete

Tags: php, php-5.6

I am using following code for making data coming from database as json format

```
   public function employeeSearch()
    {
        $arrayOfEmployee = array();
        $arrayToPush = array();
        $arrayToJSON = array();

        $new_item = $this->apicaller->sendRequest(array(
            "controller" => "Employee",
            "action" => "employeeSearch",
            "searchCriteria" => "12345"
            ));

         $arrayOfEmployee = json_decode($new_item,true);

         foreach($arrayOfEmployee as $key => $employee)
         {
              $arrayToPush = array('data' => $employee['FullName'], 'value' => $employee['_id']['$oid']);
              array_push($arrayToJSON, $arrayToPush);
         }

        echo json_encode($arrayToJSON);
    }
```

The output is

```
   [{"data":"Aasiya Rashid Khan","value":"5aa662b0d2ccda095400022f"}, 
    {"data":"Sana Jeelani Khan","value":"5aa75d8fd2ccda0fa0006187"}, 
    {"data":"Asad Hussain Khan","value":"5aaa51ead2ccda0860002692"}, 
    {"data":"Ayesha Khan Khann","value":"5aab61b4d2ccda0bc400190f"}, 
    {"data":"adhar card name","value":"5aaba0e1d2ccda0bc4001910"}
    ]
```

Now I want that json elements should look like

```
        {
"suggestions": [
    {
        "value": "Guilherand-Granges",
        "data": "750"
    },
    {
        "value": "Paris 01",
        "data": "750"
    }
    ]
    }
```

I have to implement this in jQuery autocomplete plugin...
Please help!!!

Comment: Your existing output and desired data structure don't appear to share any values. How are `"Ayesha Khan Khann"` and `"Paris 01"` related, for example? Where does `"data": "750"` come from (and do you really want `"750"`, not `750`)?

Comment: Also, what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Replace the last line with

```
echo json_encode(["suggestions" => $arrayToJSON]);
```

This should result in the wanted result!

(This hold only true if you igonre the fact that the data in `value` and `name` is not the same/similar)